# Spring - how to kill endless cycle

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, tomcat, kill

In my Spring application, there is a scheduler for executing some task. Scheduled annotation is not used there because the schedule is quite complicated - it is dynamic and it used some data from the database. So simple endless cycle with thread sleeping is used. And sleeping interval is changed according to some rules. Maybe all this can be done with Scheduled annotation, but the question is not about that.

Below is simple example:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {

        new Thread(() -> {

            while (true) {
                System.out.println(new Date());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("end");                    
                    return;
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }
}
```

The code works fine but there is some trouble with killing that new thread. When I stop the application from Tomcat this new thread is continuing to run. So on Tomcat manage page I see that application is stopped, but in Tomcat log files I still see the output from the thread.

So what the problem? How I should change the code so the thread would be killed when the application is stopped?

Comment: `break`? `return`?

Comment: Thread will stop when your application is stopped, but is started automatically when your application is restarted (because it's booted using Spring and the @PostConstruct annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement a `@PreDestroy` method which will be invoked before WebApplicationContext is closed to change a boolean flag used in your loop? Though it seems strange that your objects are not discarded even when application is stopped...

```
class Scheduler {

    private AtomicBoolean booleanFlag = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (booleanFlag.get()) {
                // do whatever you want
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy() {
        booleanFlag.set(false);
    }
}
```